# How to prove that a function is compact (closed and bounded)?

Tags: functions, optimization, compactness

The specific function I am looking at is

$f(x_1,x_2) = x_1x_2 + \frac 1{x_1} + \frac 1{x_2}$, where

for a fixed $a > 0, f(x) \le a$
and $(x1,x2) > 0 $

I'm really just looking for where to start. Do I have to look at the extremas of the function?

Comment: Hmm. Compactness is not a property of functions, but of sets...

Comment: @HansLundmark A different question then....How can I prove the function is bounded below. I am finding this especially hard to prove since the limit of f as (x,y) approaches (0,0) is undefined.

Comment: Well, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive (which you are assuming, if I interpret the notation correctly), then clearly $f(x_1,x_2)>0$, and that's a lower bound.

Comment: @HansLundmark That's embarassingly simple, thank you. However, wouldn't that make the function open, since f(x1,x2) doesn't include zero? Or is zero not really a lower limit since the limit is undefined.

Comment: Zero is a lower *bound*, not limit. Limit is something else. And the word "open" – like "compact" – usually refers to sets, not functions. (There is a concept called "open mapping" but I don't think that's what you are talking about here...)